Does Portal 2 have normal clear water?
Portal 2 has muddy/deadly water on various maps as can be seen in the screenshot below:

But I am curious, does Portal 2 have normal clear water anywhere? If yes, then where?
I know other Source games have normal clear water.
I'm planning out a map that I want to design for Portal 2 and I want the map to have normal clear water in it. So I'm trying to figure out if there is existing normal clear water somewhere in the game and how that water behaves compared to the muddy/deadly water.

Why does that matter? This seems highly trivial, and not of any use to anyone else. You can always opt to run Hammer for Portal 2 and check the textures/materials in the source files.

@Joachim it is of use. I'm planning out a map that I want to make and I want the map to have to have normal clear water. So I'm trying to figure out if there is existing normal clear water somewhere in the game and how that water behave compared to the muddy/deadly water.

But then it's even more logical to install Hammer and check the source files, because some textures might not have been used. Besides, you might want to add materials from other Source Engine games, and there are certainly some in Half-Life 2 (I believe in Portal 2, as well, by the way).

@Joachim Oh. So when using Hammer, I can use items and textures from other Source games for maps in Portal 2?

@Joachim Perhaps an explanation of how to use Hammer to find the water, is the correct answer to this question then?

I don't think so, as that's way too specific an answer to your question. I mean, setting up Hammer for Source was never a walk in the park, but since Steamworks and changes in the engine, it requires a dedicated Q&A (which I would be interested in answering :), and would just be unnecessary noise for your yes/no question here. But I'll retract my close vote.

Besides, if you're planning to make a map, you'll need to use those tools anyway, so why not install them and check for clear water? That's two birds with one stone.
